# Laravel site stopped working after reinstalling vendor

Tags: laravel, vps

I deleted webmozart from vendors and reinstalled it using composer install on my vps server, because it was conflicting with my github push. After this the website stopped working. I don't know what the error is or how to debug it. It throws an error with a file that's not the issue.

I tried deleting webmozart and composer install it on my local project and everything is fine.

I've checked my apache log right now and it seems like my autoload.php is gone.

```
[Mon Feb 10 04:16:32.1234 2020] [fcgid:warn] [pid 737] [client 0.0.0.0:293829] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  require(/home/myproject/public_html/public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/myproject/public_html/public/index.php on line 24
[Mon Feb 10 04:16:32.1234 2020] [fcgid:warn] [pid 737] [client 0.0.0.0:293829] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/myproject/public_html/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/myproject/public_html/public/index.php on line 24
```

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run

```
composer clear-cache
composer dump-autoload
```

To optimize your application read documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/deployment)

Comment: Thanks for you advice, unfortunately it didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Check what version is being referenced in your local `composer.lock` file and then compare it to the servers `composer.lock`. Also compare the `composer.json` files. There may have been some version change difference.

Comment: They are the same. I even tried copying them over manually now. and deleting the whole vendor folder and reinstalling everything. Still fails.

Comment: Very odd... can you give some more detail regarding how the files in the vendors were getting conflicts? (You shouldn't have vendors checked out) Are you also able to upload a screenshot of the error with the stack trace? Thanks.

Comment: It was wierd, I was deploying files with my github webhook, and they werent working. I checked the log, it said it wanted to delete that vendor, I don't know why as my commiting files were not related to this. So I deleted the folder. 

I have updated my original questions with an apache error that I'm getting now.

Comment: Are you sure that you weren't accidentally somehow doing your `git` commands inside a package in the vendors folder? Do you have your `/vendors/` under source control?

Comment: How far did you get with this? Can you also check your `/app/storage/logs/laravel.log` file or any file in here?

Comment: I ended up having to restore a snapshot I had luckily made 6 hours before. I actually had to do it 3 times because it kept ending up at that error after 1hour. I still don't know what it was. but the error kept happening even after all the vendors were restored again. I also turned off my webhook, and is now pulling manually in the terminal, as I felt like maybe it was the webhook who changed things. Wierd part is that it has been working fine for a year.. my vendors are not tracked in git. But thank you for trying to help, it's much appreciated!